# Edit images in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, image-processing

I want to edit images uploaded by users in the browser, before sending them to the server. Mainly I want the users to be able to add dots to places of their choosing on the picture. Right now I have the picture upload and display in the browser like so:

```
render() {
    const {user} = this.state;
    return (
        <div style={{marginTop: 150}}>
            <TakePictureComponent setImage={this.setImage}/>
            <DisplayPictureComponent image={this.state.image}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

TakePictureComponent:

```
handleChange(e) {
    const {files} = e.target;
    this.props.setImage(files[0]);
    this.setState({image: files[0]});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="file" accept="image/jpg" capture="camera"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

DisplayPictureComponent:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => this.setState({image: e.target.result});
    reader.readAsDataURL(nextProps.image);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={this.state.image} alt={''}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this works. But I need the user to be able to click on any place and add said dots. How can I achieve it? My final target is something like this (Red circles are added):

[image]

Comment: You will have to render this image on canvas then. Mark the dots there and crop it again at the time of saving. 
https://www.codicode.com/art/how_to_draw_on_a_html5_canvas_with_a_mouse.aspx

Comment: @ManishJangir Ok, thanks for the direction